# Прослушивание XMLHttpRequest get

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, xhr

Пишу скрипт для Tampermonkey, выполнение происходит на сайте с подгрузкой контента при прокрутке вниз. Для загрузки контента посылается XMLHttpRequest get запрос, нужно выполнить каждый раз код, когда контент получен и загружен на сайт. Сам к сожелению осилить не смог во всех этих аякас, jqery, xhr, запутался.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
//code
    }
  };
```

Comment: подписываемся на `onreadystatechange` следим за `readyState` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Как следить, если код добавления контента исполняется в скрипте сайта, не моем. У него все функции анонимные или локальные, тоже самое и с переменными.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/o0dfl7 вот что мне нужно прослушивать